# can I find out unique resolvers of incidents per month?

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, datepart

I've created a script that shows how many unique individuals have resolved calls in a team per month using the below script.

Is there a way to find out who the individuals are but still display the monthly figures per team based on the script I already have working?

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2) as MonthResolved, ResolvedByTeam, COUNT(DISTINCT resolvedby) as ResolvedByCnt
FROM [dbo].[Incident]
WHERE stat_datetimeresolved >= '20170401'
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2), ResolvedByTeam
ORDER BY MonthResolved asc, ResolvedByTeam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices

1. To expand your result and return separate row for each unique combination of MonthResolved, ResolvedByTeam and resolvedby. This will return more rows that your original query, because in one month/team combination you will get as many rows as resolvers.
2. To add one more column to your query, in which to return a list (for example comma separated) with the names of the resolvers. This can be done easily with [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, but it is available in SQL Server 2017 and newer only. For 2008 your option is to perform some ugly conversions using [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

Here are both queries, for implementing options 1 and 2:

```
;with cte1 as (
SELECT
    CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2) as MonthResolved
    , ResolvedByTeam
    , resolvedby
FROM [dbo].[Incident]
WHERE stat_datetimeresolved >= '20170401'
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2), ResolvedByTeam, resolvedby
)
select
    MonthResolved
    , ResolvedByTeam
    , (select count(distinct resolvedby) as Name
       from [dbo].[Incident] i 
       where CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2) = cte1.MonthResolved
         and i.ResolvedByTeam = cte1.ResolvedByTeam)
    , resolvedby
from cte1
ORDER BY MonthResolved asc, ResolvedByTeam, resolvedby

;with cte2 as (
SELECT
    CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2) as MonthResolved
    , ResolvedByTeam
    , COUNT(DISTINCT resolvedby) as ResolvedByCnt
FROM [dbo].[Incident]
WHERE stat_datetimeresolved >= '20170401'
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2), ResolvedByTeam
)

select *
from cte2
cross apply (select (
    select distinct resolvedby + ', ' as [text()]
    from [dbo].[Incident] 
    where ResolvedByTeam = cte2.ResolvedByTeam
        and CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2) = cte2.MonthResolved
    for xml path ('')) as Names) t
ORDER BY MonthResolved asc, ResolvedByTeam
```

Comment: Would it be straightforward to get this on a daily basis? I'm assuming by removing the date formatting sections, this would produce daily information?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, unless stat_datetimeresolved also contain time. In this case just cast it to date to get rid of the time. And, please, do not forget the accept and upvote the helpful answers! :)

Comment: The stat_datetimeresolved does contain a time value within it. Does that make it tricky to do?

Comment: No, just replace "CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2)" with CAST(stat_datetimeresolved as DATE).